# How do I resolve a type-error that int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'datetime.datetime' in polls app?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

My models.py is

```
class Question(models.Model):
    CATEGORY_SIZES = (
    ('W', 'WORlD'),
    ('T', 'TECHNOLOGY'),
    ('S', 'SCREEN'),
    ('P', 'SPORTS')
)
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length= 100)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('Date Is Published')
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="Question_Image", blank=True)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=CATEGORY_SIZES)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question_text

class Choice(models.Model):
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length= 200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default= 0)
    image2 = models.ImageField(upload_to="Question_Image2", blank=True)
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete= models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return  self.choice_text

    def vote_range(self):
        return range(0, self.votes)
```

And, I added four views in format inside views.py

```
def world(request):
    latest_questions = Question.objects.filter(category='W')
    context = {'latest_questions': latest_questions}
    return render(request, 'polls/world.html',context)
```

Then, I ran a command

```
python manage.py makemigrations polls
```

and set timezone.now as default for category

Then, I ran another command

```
python manage.py migrate
```

And, I got this type error that

> TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a
>   number, not 'datetime.datetime'

Comment: why you pass String in DateTimeField() ?

Comment: what must i do there? But i don't think that's a problem for type error.

Comment: Give your Table Schema

Answer (score 0):

Check your column data type same as your model

```
from future import unicode_literals
from django.db import models, migrations
import datetime

class Migration(migrations.Migration):
    dependencies = [ ('polls', 'file_name'), ]
    operations = [
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='choice',
            name='question',
            field=models.ForeignKey(default=1, to='polls.Question', on_delete= models.CASCADE), preserve_default=False ),
    ]
```

From your migration file it's normal that you get this error, you are trying to store a datetime on a Foreignkey which need to be an int.

This is happened when the migration asked you which value will be set for old Choice rows because the new ForeignKey is required.

To resolve it, you can change the migration file and change the datetime.date... to a valid id from the Question table like the code bellow. **Or delete all the migration file and re-run** ./manage.py makemigrations, when you will be asked about the default value prompt a valid Question id, not a datetime.

Comment: for customizing args

Comment: Why use options? just use models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

Comment: i think your datatype of DB is not match  ?

Comment: what is your Table schema

Comment: It gives a TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'on_delete'

Comment: add on_delete= models.CASCADE in ForeignKey

Comment: django.db.migrations.exceptions.NodeNotFoundError: Migration polls.0015_auto_20180214_1531 dependencies reference nonexistent parent node ('polls', '0003_remove_choice_question')

Comment: Above error is shown in python manage.py makemigrations polls

Comment: how could i know the file_name

Comment: its your migration file name inside the migration folder

Answer (score 0):

The Set default date of the form.

```
  default=datetime.datetime(2018, 02, 14, 17, 1, 28, 128127, tzinfo=utc)
```

Comment: where should i add the default date of the form?

Comment: field=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, default=datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 26, 17, 1, 41, 794803, tzinfo=utc))

Comment: "name datetime is not defined" error when i ran python manage.py makemigrations polls

Comment: you need to import the module datetime first:                                        
      >>import datetime

Comment: "name utc is not defined" is the recent error after i added from datetime import datetime and import datetime

Comment: Add                                                                                                            
from django.utils.timezone import utc

Comment: Still i m getting the same type-error that int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'datetime.datetime' after i do python manage.py migrate

Comment: why use auto_now = True and default time together

Comment: i have edited it as pub_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True) but still the error is same

Comment: In migration file set   (preserve_default=False)                     migrations.AddField(
            model_name='choice',
            name='question',
            field=models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 
            26, 17, 1, 23, 211181, tzinfo=utc)),
           preserve_default=False,)        Also I would adopted the approach to kill the database and all of the migrations  under the migrations folder delete ALL of the migrations .py files - this will prevent these from being applied again when the database is recreated and then to migrate again

Answer (score 0):

Delete the migrations folder inside the app and again run :

```
python manage.py makemigrations <appname>
python manage.py migrate
```